# Show how much reputation you'e earned today/How much more you can earn

Tags: feature-request, reputation

A nice feature addition would be if I could see how much reputation I've earned in the "Stack Overflow" day and/or how much more reputation I can earn "today". This would be available in each user's profile somewhere and would be private knowledge to the individual.

Comment: This is easy enough to see in your Recent Activity page.  Click the envelope to bring up the page, Reputation tab, click "today".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to your summary (click the envelope icon at the top of the page) then click the "today" tab you'll see how much rep you've earned today.

[image: Daily Rep]

The reputation cap is 200, so you can figure out how much you have left to go.  (Of course you can always earn more by having answers accepted after you've reached the cap.)

Comment: No points to Stack Exchange for ease of use, eh? Thanks, now I know.

Comment: @mririgo: It probably is one click and a math op too many from a usability standpoint.  The default time frame when you click the envelope is roughly "since the last time you clicked the envelope," which arguably *is* useful, so I can see why they made it the default.

Answer (score 1):

You already can see how much reputation you've earned in a day.  Click on the envelope next to your name, then Reputation/Today.  As for how much more you can earn... do some simple math, the Rep limit is 200 a day (not including accepted answers and bounty).